# PHP/SQL - Setting SQL Result to a list

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how to turn a SQL Query into a variable like this one:

```
$in = "Lambo 1; Trabant 2; Car 3;";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
```

The query currently comes back with `Lambo 1; Trabant 2; Car 3;` but how would I change it into $in? As if I currently run it through another func I get`explode() expects parameter 2 to be string,`

Full code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';
    $database = '';
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);

$SteamID = "STEAM_0:0:81010017";
$sql_query="SELECT _Inventory FROM Players Where _SteamID='$SteamID'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);


$in = $result;
foreach (explode(";", $in) as $element) {
        $element = trim($element);
        if (strpos($element, " ") !== false ) {
                list($car, $number) = explode(" ", $element);
                echo $car;
        }
}


?>
```

Comment: have you tried using mysql_fetch_array() instead of  sql_query()?

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: see the answers with the hint from my comment - this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `$in` variable to:

```
$in = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
```

Comment: Breaks the code and just displays a HTTP Error 500.

Comment: can you `var_dump($result)`??

Comment: Thanks, a small typo in the code caused it. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_query returns false or a mysqli_result object.

You need to add something to actually get the results - either by calling fetch_object, fetch_array, fetch_assoc as shown below:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $group_arr[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't work when using this line of code, still bringing up a HTTP 500 Error

Comment: `need to add something` means not `need to use this line of code`